# Bootstran navigation .active link it is not adding the class .active to current link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

This is may html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Blog Site</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="{{ route('blogs.index') }}">Blogs</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('blogs.create') }}">Create</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have the `bootstrap.min.js` but the active link it is not working. Then I tried to do the trick with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".nav a").on("click", function(){
      $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
   });
});
```

but when I click the class `.active` is added but then it goes away. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You're probably navigating to `blogs.create` when you click that link. So jquery adds the `active` class, then the page reloads, and you've got `active` hardcoded to the `blogs.index` route. You either need to check your current page when assigning the `active` class, or prevent navigation (if you're just trying to see that the class is being applied as expected).

Comment: Bootstrap is just styling your page, it's not its work to guess which is active or not, it's yours..., so it's not an issue...

Comment: Bootstrap has many components not related to style and comes with this functionality out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know but in Laravel `.active` links works different, it is called **active state** so the way I did it with jquery doesn't work because you are dealing with **routes**.

Then I used a great package from **Dwight Watson** called **Active**: https://packagist.org/packages/watson/active

that does it the Laravel way.